# How to convert a dynamic XAML into a PNG or GIF using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, png

I'm creating dynamic templated XAML designs that I would like to convert to PNG or GIF from my C# code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`RenderTargetBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) class. MSDN has [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969775.aspx) of how to convert a `Visual` to an image.

Comment: `RenderTargetBitmap` + `PngBitmapEncoder` (the latter described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Found an interesting article on how to do this...

[Converting and customizing XAML to PNG with server-side WPF](https://web.archive.org/web/20130930171157/http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2008/10/10/converting-and-customizing-xaml-to-png-with-server-side-wpf.aspx)